# Graph coloring algorithm's complexity

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, coloring

Given a graph $G$, i have to talk about the number of ways to color this graph properly (so that no adjacent vertices have the same color). As an algorithm, i used the "Welsh-Powell" Algorithm. I have read in several references that the complexity of this algorithm for graph coloring is $O(n^2)$, but i can't find a way to prove it. Does anyone know how to show this result? Perhaps even mentioning the maximum number of colors required for this algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The Welsh–Powell algorithm is just the greedy algorithm where the vertices are considered in order of decreasing degree. That it is $O(n^2)$ stems from the fact that it considers each edge once when assigning a colour to a vertex. The maximum number of colours it may require is one more than the maximum degree of the graph.

Comment: But i have read that the number of colors required for the Welsh-Powell algorithm is $max_i min\{d_i(v), i\}$. Which one is correct? Which are the steps that lead to the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: @HulufHailé Did you read the Wikipedia page properly? "...at most one more than the graph’s maximum degree."

Comment: You have to go through every possible color also for every node and each of its neighbor. So intuitively it seems like a worst case of $n$ colors for $n$ nodes, each connected to all the other $n-1$ nodes, sounding more like $O(n^3)$.

Comment: @dekuShrub I am going through a list of at most $n-1$ nodes for each of $n$ nodes.

Comment: Didn't understand how to implement the algorithm first. But yeah, you're right. It works with an array with availability-flags for colors indexed by the color's number.

Comment: I actually have the same thought of @dekuShrub, but everywhere it's said that the complexity is $O(n^2)$. Can you tell me why is not $O(n^3)$??

Comment: @HulufHailé See what I said to deku.

Comment: @HulufHailé and also see my comment mentioning an array. You can lookup all colors in a loop that is in sequence with the loop that checks all neighbour nodes (IF you store the results indexed by colors in an array which then uses $O(1)$ lookup).